# Handling asynchronous response in JS - limited access to JS files that can be edited

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I am modifying a third party - web client application in which I only have access to certain js files. 
The search function is limited to search in one given server node at a time, and as a work around, I hardcoded all the server nodes and created a for loop, invoking the "search" several times, at different nodes.

The server response (in a form of FORM - without getters) are automatically handled by a callback, which then renders the view of the form. This means I am only able to display the last response and thus displaying only one set of result.

To handle this, I added `$trs = $(tr).clone(true)` on the callback function, saving all the rows from previous forms and then - I made the last loop to "search" to have another callback - which will then append the collected rows from $tr and display the last form complete with all the results from all nodes.

But the result is inconsistent. It sometimes just displays result from one server node. I would think this is caused by some delay in server response which caused that form to render last. I tried to put delay by `setTimeout` function, but that keeps me from getting any result at all

I am very new with all the web programming - JS and JQUERY both (well CSS and HTML even lol) and I would like to ask for your suggestions on a better way to handle this.

Thank you!

```
 _handleConfigSubmit: function (form, error) {
        //alert("_handleConfigSubmit");

        if (form) {
            var formView = new jabberwerx.ui.XDataFormView(form);                
            var that = this;

             formView.event("xdataItemSelected").bind(function(evt) {

                that.jq.find(".muc_search_button_join").removeAttr("disabled");

                var resultTable = that.jq.find(".muc_search_results table.result_table");
                resultTable.find("tr.selected").removeClass("selected");

                that._selectedItem = evt.data.selected;
                resultTable.find("tr#"+evt.data.selected._guid).addClass("selected");
            });

           var searchResultsDiv = jabberwerx.$(".muc_search_results", this.jq);
           searchResultsDiv.empty();
            this.update();
            var dim = {
                width: searchResultsDiv.width(),
                height: searchResultsDiv.height()
            };
            formView.render().appendTo(searchResultsDiv);
            formView.dimensions(dim);

            $trs = $("table.result_table tbody>tr:not(:first)").clone(true);
            if ($trList!=null){
                $trList = $trList.add($trs);
            }else{
                $trList = $trs;
            }

            $("table.result_table tbody>tr:not(:first)").remove()

            if (ctr<=3){
                $("table.result_table tbody").append($trList);
            }else{
                ctr++;
            }


        } else {
            this._showError(error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Probably the last callback is not the one you expect it to be

Comment: Hello Dandavis, added the code in the original post

Comment: Can you be more clear in your question, and narrow the problem down to a more digestible size?  The good thing about JavaScript is that you can change whatever you want from another script.

Comment: Hello Bergi, most of the time the code will work fine, but there will be times that I am able to see the consolidated list then it will be replaced by a list from one node only - I am guessing on this times, there are delay in responses and app is done displaying the second (supposed to be final) method when it processes the delayed response -therefore displaying the incomplete list.

Comment: Hello Brad, What I want to achieve is a way to synchronize the callbacks. Or to put a sort of delay in the for loop - so that it will only enter the next loop once the callback has executed.

Comment: +1 @Brad Yes. The rendering of the response could be easily replaced by overriding the functions that render to the view.

Comment: Hello Bart, I am not sure if I get what you mean, sorry. Can you please explain further?

Comment: Is there a way I can get the DOM via jquery before rendering the page? As I understand I have to render the DOM first so jquery can get elements/values from it.

Comment: I was able to accomplish my goal by adding a counter in the callback function. So now I only have one callback function, which appends the list at the last server response. I have posted the modified code at original post.  But I am sure there is a more efficient way to handle this.